# gdb how to step until end of statement ("n" does not do it!)

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, g++

in GDB with C++ on LINUX:

How to step until the end of the current statement?
The `n`  (next statement) command performs many steps and one never knows, if one already has reached the end of the current statement (or the beginning of the next).
I'm not talking about curly braces.
I'm talking about executing a single assignment.

Comment: Next is supposed to go line by line, not statement by statement. In addition to that: is the binary compiled with optimizations turned on? On a second thought: one or several step commands or breakpoint inside the assignment operator are not viable either?

Answer (score 1):

> How to step until the end of the current statement?

There isn't an easy way to achieve this, so don't put multiple statements on a single line.

If there is a single statement on each line, then `next` command will do what you want.